# How do you load and boot an ISO over GRUB2

Tags: boot, grub2, grub, iso

I am trying to boot OpenVZ 7 over KVM via ISO. I can't seem to figure out where I am going wrong with my GRUB2 entry.

What I have so far:

```
menuentry "Kernel 4.4.30-mod-std-ipv6-64" {
        load_video
        set gfxpayload=keep
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod diskfilter
        insmod mdraid09
        insmod ext2
        set root='mduuid/77bf0bb5a19120e8a4d2adc226fd5302'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint='mduuid/77bf0bb5a19120e8a4d2adc226fd5302'  7c7de7f6-0868-4daa-8248-b78e85fe4ac9
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 7c7de7f6-0868-4daa-8248-b78e85fe4ac9
        fi
        linux   /boot/bzImage-4.4.30-mod-std-ipv6-64 root=/dev/md2 ro crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet rd.md.uuid=77bf0bb5:a19120e8:a4d2adc2:26fd5302 rd.md.uuid=621712a2:b7f36559:a4d2adc2:26fd5302
        initrd /boot/initramfs-4.4.30-mod-std-ipv6-64.img
}

menuentry "ISO" {
 set isoname="openvz-iso-7.0.4"
 set isofile="/root/${isoname}.iso"
 set rdfile="/isolinux/initrd0.img"
 loopback loop $isofile
 linux (loop)/isolinux/vmlinuz0 root=live:CDLABEL=$isoname rootfstype=auto ro rd.live.image quiet rhgb rd.luks=0 rd.md=0 rd.dm=0 iso-scan/filename=${isofile}
 initrd (loop)$rdfile
}
```

This is my fist time trying to do this with GRUB2.

Error:

```
Error: file '/isolinux/vmlinuz0' not found
Error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

EDIT:
Guessing this is probably just due to not being a LIVE CD?

Comment: I see an error `loopback loop $isofile`  `loopback loop (hd0,1)$isofile` when your isofile is on the first HD on the first partiton.  Can you show the whole Grub-Skript for your ISO?